# How to get recently authenticated user?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, cookies

I am working with MVC 3 and I have just implemented a wrapper for the FormsAuthenticationService.

Something similar to the following.

```
public void SignIn(string username, bool createPersistantCookie)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Value Cannot be null or empty", "username");

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, createPersistantCookie);
}
```

Reluctantly, I have gotten this to work, but now I am not quite sure how to get the information that I have stored.

Once the user is in my system, how can I now safely retrieve this information if I need to grab their UserID out of the database?

Comment: What type of information do you need to retrieve? Just their UserId? If so, that can be stored inside the forms cookie without having to hit the database. Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the additional information provided, you want to store additional data with the FormsAuthentication ticket. To do so, you need first create a custom FormsAuthentication ticket:

**Storing Data**

Grab the current HttpContext (not worrying about testability)

```
var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
```

Determine when the ticket should expire:

```
var expires = isPersistent 
                ? DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout) 
                : NoPersistenceExpiryDate; // NoPersistenceExpiryDate = DateTime.MinValue
```

Create a new FormsAuthentication ticket to hold your custom data.

```
var authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                             1, 
                             username, 
                             DateTime.Now, 
                             DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout), 
                             isPersistent, 
                             "My Custom Data String"); //Limit to about 1200 bytes max
```

Create your HTTP cookie

```
new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket))
  {
    Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
    Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain,
    Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
    Expires = expires,
    HttpOnly = true
  };
```

And finally add to the response

```
httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

**Retrieving Data**

Then you can retrieve your data on subsequent requests by parsing the stored authentication ticket...

Again, grab current HttpContext

```
var httpContext = HttpContext.Current
```

Check to see if the request has been authenticated (call in Application_AuthenticateRequest or OnAuthorize)

```
if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    return false;
```

Check to see if you have a FormsAuthentication ticket available and that it has not expired:

```
var formsCookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
if (formsCookie == null)
  return false;
```

Retrieve the FormsAuthentication ticket:

```
var authenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(formsCookie.Value);
if (authenticationTicket.Expired)
  return false;
```

And finally retrieve your data:

```
var data = authenticationTicket.UserData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually stored a user id in the database.  All the code that you've written does is store an authentication cookie on the users computer, either as a session cookie (not persistent) or as a persistent one.

When your page refreshes, it will get the cookie automatically, decode it, and populate the IPrincipal object which you access from the `User.Current` property of your controller.

Comment: I apologize, I really just explained my question incorrectly. I meant how do I access what I have just stored in the cookie. I plan on storing something aside from the username eventually, and I just want to know how I can access it off the cookie...